# No rule to make target Install (Kubuntu Konsole)

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, sh

I am trying to install the following database: [aleda-latest.zip](https://gforge.inria.fr/frs/?group_id=482&release_id=8011)

In the Konsole I type the following command:

```
$ make install
```

---

```
output:
bzcat ne_vars.fr.dat.bz2 > ne_vars.fr.dat
bzcat ne_refs.fr.dat.bz2 > ne_refs.fr.dat
make: *** No rule to make target« /usr/local/share/alexina/fr », needed by « lefff.dat ». Stop.
```

---

- What seems to be the problem?
- Am I missing steps?

Comment: most software that uses `make` also requires that you use `./configure` before that. Good luck.

Comment: yes, actdually, it `./configure && make && sudo make install`. Depending on what userID you want to use as the "owner" of the software, you may need more `sudo`s or fewer ;-/ Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some target in that makefile lists that directory as a prerequisite but there is no target that tells make how to create that directory in the makefile.

Either the makefile is broken or it expects some other software to have created that directory for it already (something `alexina` related presumably).